# Memory Leak in a TWebBroser component in Lazarus

Tags: memory-leaks, freepascal, lazarus

Operating system is Windows 7, Using Lazarus V. 2.2.6. (Pascal)
I am opening a web page repeatedly in a loop and the Memory usage increases with each iteration. Using Task manager, I have looked at the memory usage as it goes through the program and have identified the culprit as the following code. Please read the commented parts to see what the memory status is.

---

```
      [`BusyPanel.visible := True;` //Now reading 7016 Kb
      lpBuffer := 0;
      `InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, @lpBuffer, SizeOf(lpBuffer));
      InternetSetOption(nil,INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, @lpBuffer, SizeOf(lpBuffer));` //Now reading 7652    Kb
      `InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, nil, 0);`// End the previous session
              // This ADDS **600+ Kb** to the count
       `ActiveXContainer1.Active:=true;`

    `**WebBrowser1.ComServer.Navigate(PathToWebPage, onull,onull,onull,onull);`//Now reading 8476 Kb
    `While WebBrowser1.comserver.ReadyState <> ReadyState_Complete Do`
            `Begin`
            `Sleep(100);`
            `Application.ProcessMessages;` // This MUST be included
            `End;**`
```

// After opening web page memory is **145,888 Kb**
// This is inside of a loop so the leak gets worse with each iteration.
`BusyPanel.visible := False;` // After opening web page memory is 145,888 Kb

// *********Experiment to remove memory 10th May 2023***********
// Was reading 134000K

// Release the document interface
`Doc := nil; //  Reading 133,900 Kb`
// Release the web browser control interface
`Doc := WebBrowser1.ComServer.Document as IHTMLDocument2;` ](https://stackoverflow.com)

---

I have been trying to solve this leak for about two months and have tried releasing, Freeing, etc

I cannot find a way to get the memory released.
Help!!
Many thanks in advance

Laurence.

The following, which have been commented out at the moment is a list of "Failures" (Ha-Ha).
`//WebBrowser1.comserver.Stop;
//WebBrowser1.ComServer.Document._Release; // Reading  133,000 NO DIFFERENCE

```
  //WebBrowser1.ComServer._Release;// Reading 133,916 Has increased
  //WebBrowser1.ComServer.free;
  //ActiveXContainer1.ComServer := nil;

  // Release the ActiveX component
  //ActiveXContainer1.Active := False;  // Now reading  95,820 Kb
  //ActiveXContainer1.ComServer._Release;

  // Now Reading  95,820 Kb
 //WebBrowser1.DestroyComponents;
  //WebBrowser1.free;`
```

//WebBrowser1.ComServer.Document := nil;

After about 50 iterations my computer reports "Out Of Memory, Line 1". I have some 32Gb of memory in my machine.
**None of the previous answers appear to address the particular lines of code which I have identified as being the culprit.**
Thank you,
Laurence